# Less verbose templated private static const member variable specialisation

Tags: c++, constants, static-members, template-specialization, c++17

So if I want to specialise:

```
template<typename T>
class my_class{
       private:
          static const std::string my_string;
        };
```

The only way I was able to do it was via

```
template<> const std::string my_class<some_type>::my_string = "the string";
```

Let's say I have a bunch of private static members and a bunch of specialisations.

Is there a cleaner way to do this? closer to:

```
my_class<some_type>::my_string = "the string";
```

Comment: Variable templates, perhaps?

Comment: It's probably a good shoot, but I couldn't figure out how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is tag dispatching.

```
template<class T> struct tag_t{using type=T;};
template<class T> constexpr tag_t<T> tag={};

auto make_my_string(tag_t<some_type>){return "the string";}
```

then:

```
template<typename T>
class my_class{
private:
  static const std::string my_string;
};

template<class T>
static const std::string my_class<T>::my_string = make_my_string( tag<T> );
```

The per-type overhead is:

```
auto make_my_string(tag_t<some_type>){return "the string";}
```

which is cleaner than the alternative.  As an advantage, you can define `make_my_string` in the namespace adjacent to `some_type`, and `my_class` should automatically pick it up via ADL.

As you have a pile of private static const members, you could also put them all into their own struct.  Then you can have one function make all of them for a given type, instead of one function per private static const member.